# Bishul Akum and Scrambled Eggs

Tags: halacha, eggs, bishul-akum

Does bishul akum apply to scrambled eggs? Maybe it's not oleh al shulkhan melekh.
Looking for sources, preferably Sephardic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[“Daily Halachah” by Rabbi Eli Mansour](https://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1649) states:

> The Ben Ish Hai lists a number of common foods that are subject to
>   this prohibition, including rice, truffles and eggs. Even though one
>   could drink an egg yolk without cooking it, nevertheless, since people
>   normally cook eggs, it is included in this prohibition. **Thus, one may
>   not allow his non-Jewish housekeeper, for example, to prepare
>   scrambled eggs for him,** even if she uses his utensils and prepares the
>   eggs in his kitchen. Similarly, at catered affairs, gentile employees
>   should not prepare omelets and the like for the Jewish guests.

At [Kashrus.org](http://kashrut.org/forum/search.asp?page=23&keyword=akum) question 226, “Can you order scrambled eggs at a non-kosher restaurant?” was answered “No, it's Bishul Akum.”

Comment: @Double "Any posek who says it's asur now by just quoting the shulchan arukh should be fired as a posek." You got one Chacham and one organization to go fire.

Comment: @user6591, the Ben Ish Hai [doesn't quote anybody](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=412&hilite=).

Comment: @Yishai as per Double AA's argument that would be irrelevant. He lived long ago in a country far away.

Answer (score 0):

Shulchan Aruch Sfardi enough for you?:) siman 113 in Yoreh Deah siff 14 says bishul akum applies to eggs. No differentiation is made how they were cooked.

Comment: Note that the standard for אינו עולה על שולחן מלכים may vary with changing mores over time and locale (in support of this, see for e.g. *Chochmas Adam* 66:4 "כללו של דבר הכל הולך אחר המקום מה שדרך לאכול באותו מקום" and *Aruch HaShulchan* YD 113:18). Even so, I'd say that scrambled eggs nowadays probably do qualify as עולה על שולחן מלכים.

Comment: Citing a modern source would be much more powerful, as these standards are time and place dependent.

Comment: @Fred, do sefardi poskim agree that it is time and place dependent? It certainly isn't universally agreed (unless you are suggesting that eggs in any form are no longer עולה על שולחן מלכים).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23869/discussion-on-answer-by-user6591-bishul-akum-and-scrambled-eggs).